# Salesforce activities to look after power outage

Tags: jobs

There is a scheduled power outage at our office a month later. Are there any things generic to check after power is back up. (Power outage is not salesforce outage, its our office bldg outage)

For eg.., we verified the file storage is AWS S3 for us, so no issue
we verified email service if its on-prem, its office 365, so no issue

Are there any such general things to verify during this outage. While this may be our company-specific architecture what services are on-prem and what are on cloud, any common activities that you may think of, will help

Best Regards
NSK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce being a cloud based CRM, your infrastructure/power outage won't affect anything on your Salesforce instance. I am assuming you don't have any proxy server in place for your instance URL or communities. Even If you happen to have proxy server in place, your communities will be up and running on their original domains but your proxy URLs won't work. And definitely no data loss will happen.

Comment: Thank you Asish